# Cocoa: Interrupt main thread to check for new key events?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa

I have a basic Cocoa app with a search field. As the user types the first letter, a search is started that can take a while.

As soon as the user types the second letter, the first search should be canceled and started with the new search string.

The search itself must happen on the main thread.

Is there a way to periodically "pause" the search task running on the main thread and have the main thread process any pending key events instead?

I tried adding the following, but it does not quite work. The cursor blinks, but new letters typed don't show up.

```
let untilDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.25)
while NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().runMode(NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode, beforeDate: untilDate)
{
    print("did process")
}
```

PS: An alternative solution would be to hold off with the search after the first letter for a brief amount to see if the user is going to type more. However, if there would be a way to accomplish the above, the search would complete even faster.

Comment: Why do you need the search on the main thread ? If it's going to take time it should **not** be performed on the main thread !

Comment: Yes, I know. But the search is accessing UI elements and must be done on the main thread, unfortunately.

Comment: Well then your approach must be terribly broken I'm sorry. You should separate data and UI elements. Messing with the main runLoop manually is a bad idea, and it's only going to lead you to more problems and a low performance app.

Comment: I'm traversing a tree of UI elements and those can only be accessed from the main thread. I was just curious to learn if there's such a way as pausing execution while letting the main thread process queued up events.